# In a closed subspace A of a complete metric space, are there two points such that $d(x,y) = \mathop{Diam}(A)$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

If we have a complete metric space $X$ and $A$ is closed, bounded subspace, do there necessarily exist points $x,y \in A$ such that $d(x,y) =  $ Diam$(A)$?

Clearly if $X$ is not complete we cannot say this. For example in $\mathbb Q$ the subspace $\mathbb Q \cap(\pi, \pi +1)$ has diameter 1 but no two points achieve this distance.

You can say there are points $x_n, y_n \in A$ such that $d(x_n, y_n) \ge $ Diam$(A) - \frac{1}{n}$ for any natural number $n$. If these sequences converge in $X$ they converge in $A$ and it follows that the distance of the limits is the diameter. But there is no reason the sequences should converge. For example take $A$ the closed unit disc and $x_n = (1- \frac{1}{n}, n), y_n = (1- \frac{1}{n}, n + \pi)$ in polar coordinates.

Another idea I had was taking the metric as a continuous function $d: X \times X \to \mathbb R$ and considering the preimage $d^{-1}([0, $Diam$(A) - \frac{1}{n}])$. These sets are closed in $X\times X$, so their intersection with $A\times A$ is also closed, and hence they form a decreasing sequence of closed subsets of $A\times A$. But I don't see sufficient information to conclude that their intersection, which would contain the pair we seek, is nonempty.

Comment: Note that both ideas would work if $A$ was compact. So it holds for $X = \mathbb{R}^n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there might be no such points $x$ and $y$. Consider $X=\ell_1$. Let $e_n$ be the standard basis in $\ell_1$. Let $A = \{(1-1/n)e_n\}$. Space $X$ is a complete space, $A$ is bounded and closed. The diameter of $A$ is $2$ but there is no $x,y\in A$ with $d(x,y) = \|x-y\|_1 = 2$.

The statement is true if we assume additionally that $A$ is compact.

Answer (score 3):

This is false without compactness assumption. Just take an infinite-dimensional Hilbert space and a sequence of pairwise orthogonal vectors of the norm $1-1/n$.